# Display django registration form errors

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I want to display registration errors when the user is trying to register but he does somthing wrong like typing an existing email address or the two passwords don't match or when one of the django's default password validator is not considred like typing a short password, and be able to style each error with bootstrap alert as i'm showing below in the template

the user model in models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from django.conf import settings

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="Email",max_length=250, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, null=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    full_name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Full name", max_length=150, null=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['full_name']

    objects = MyAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name

    # For checking permissions.
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    # For which users are able to view the app (everyone is)
    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

the view that has the sign up/registration form in views.py

```
def home(request):

    user = request.user

    # for rendring texts

    form = TextForm()

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TextForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            author = User.objects.filter(email=user.email).first()
            obj.author = author
            form.save()
            form = TextForm()

    texts = Text.objects.all().order_by('-id')

    # for signing in

    if request.POST:
        signin_form = SigninForm(request.POST)
        if signin_form.is_valid():
            email = request.POST['email']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
            if user:
                login(request, user)
            elif user is None:
                messages.error(request,'ُEmail or password is incorrect')
    else:
        signin_form = SigninForm()


    
    # for signing up

        signup_form = SignupForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        signup_form = SignupForm(request.POST)
        if signup_form.is_valid():
            User = signup_form.save()
            full_name = signup_form.cleaned_data.get('full_name')
            email = signup_form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            raw_password = signup_form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            account = authenticate(email=email, password=raw_password)
            login(request, account)
        else:
            signup_form = SignupForm()
        

    context = {'signin_form':signin_form,'signup_form':signup_form,'form': form, 'texts': texts}

    return render(request, 'main/home.html', context)
```

my sign up form in forms.py

```
class SignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={'placeholder': 'Password', 'class': 'form-control mt-3'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={'placeholder': 'Confirm your password', 'class': 'form-control mt-3 mb-3', }))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("full_name", "email", "password1", "password2")
        widgets = {
            'full_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Full name', 'class': 'form-control mb-3', }),
            'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email', 'class': 'form-control', }),
        }
```

in the template

```
 <div id="signup" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
                        <form action="" method="POST">
                            {% csrf_token %}

                            {{signup_form.full_name}}

                            {{signup_form.email}}

                            {{signup_form.password1}}

                            {{signup_form.password2}}


                            <button class="btn btn-success form-control" type="submit">Sign up</button>



                            {% if signup_form.errors %}
                            {% for field in signup_form %}
                            {% for error in field.errors %}
                            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show"> {{ error}}

                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>

                            </div>
                            {% endfor %}
                            {% endfor %}
                            {% endif %}
                        </form>
```

i tried form.errors instead of signup_form.errors it rendered errors of another form which is in the same template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you call `form.is_valid()` the instance of the form becomes really important if there are errors, because those errors exist on that instance. So you need to pass that back to the user in order to display the errors.

A simple example of what I mean by this would be;

```
    def register(request):
        form = CustomUserCreationForm()
            
        if request.method == "POST":
    
            form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
    
            if form.is_valid():
                user = form.save(commit=False)
    
                user.is_valid = False
                user.save()
                # Maybe redirect here
            else:
                messages.info(request, 'invalid registration details')
                
        return render(
            request, "users/register.html",
            {"form": form}
        )
```

And with that, you can then iterate over the errors in the template.

```html
    <form method="post" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}

        {% if form.non_field_errors %}
            {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
                {{ error }}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}

        {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
            {{ hidden }}
        {% endfor %}

        {% for field in form %}
            {{ field }}
            {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
        {% endfor %}

        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

A more generic template like this will also help you because you can reuse it for any form, rather than specifying the particular form & field names like in your example.

Another thing I'd point out is that there is a lot of complexity in your view, lots of checks for the request method for example. And also 3 different forms. If you've got different forms in a page you can name the submit buttons so that you can check which form is being submitted. I've got an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63945115/1199464) to show how to handle multiple forms.

You're doing `user.email` without checking if the user is authenticated or checking if an email exists, so there's an error also waiting to happen there.

So to simplify your view you could do something like this (after naming your form buttons);

```py
def home(request):
    user = request.user

    # for rendering texts
    text_form = TextForm()
    signin_form = SigninForm()
    signup_form = SignupForm()

    if request.method == "POST":
        if 'text_form' in request.POST:
            text_form = TextForm(request.POST)
            if text_form.is_valid() and request.user.is_authenticated:
                obj = text_form.save(commit=False)
                author = User.objects.filter(email=user.email).first()
                obj.author = author
                text_form.save()

        if 'signin_form' in request.POST:
            signin_form = SigninForm(request.POST)
            if signin_form.is_valid():
                email = request.POST['email']
                password = request.POST['password']
                user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
                if user:
                    login(request, user)
                elif user is None:
                    messages.error(request, 'ُEmail or password is incorrect')

        if 'signup_form' in request.POST:
            signup_form = SignupForm(request.POST)
            if signup_form.is_valid():
                User = signup_form.save()
                full_name = signup_form.cleaned_data.get('full_name')
                email = signup_form.cleaned_data.get('email')
                raw_password = signup_form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
                account = authenticate(email=email, password=raw_password)
                login(request, account)

    texts = Text.objects.all().order_by('-id')

    context = {
        'signin_form': signin_form,
        'signup_form': signup_form,
        'text_form': text_form,
        'texts': texts
    }

    return render(request, 'main/home.html', context)
```

Comment: great explanation, i appreciate it , i'll let u know if i face any errors or issues.

Comment: when i try to create a post i get an error "local variable 'User' referenced before assignment" i think that this error happens when a variable isn't defined while me trying to prosses it but i think that it's defined my models.py , can u explain this to me!

Comment: the error is in this line "author = User.objects.filter(email=user.email).first()"

Comment: If the case that you've provided is accurate (`User`) that suggests you're not importing your user model. `User` in your code implies that you're importing the user model at the top of the file in order to query it.

Comment: what do u mean & i have in the top of the file "from .models import * " what should i do ?

Comment: You should probably give this a read; https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-best-practices-referencing-user-model